# Probability of forming an N-symbol cluster in a MxM matrix

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

I have the following task: A 7x7 matrix with empty slots in each cell we must put a symbol randomly selected from 1000 symbols 25% of them are the symbol B(250 Bs).
The matrix is filled with symbols from the 1000 symbol pool. What is the probability of forming a 5 or more symbols clusters with Bs? (A cluster is a segment where a symbol has adjacent same symbol. Diagonals are not included.) Here is an example of a cluster:
[Cluster example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hnGI.png)

Using computer simulations I get a probability around 30% and a probability of exactly 5 symbol cluster around 14%. However, I cant manually reach these numbers with mathematics. My approach was to use the hypergeometric distribution but the numbers I got were not relevant. Because with hypergeometric distribution I get all the possible ways of getting exactly 5 Bs randomly. Then I divide them by all the possible ways to arrange the matrix and I get `0.005196` which is no way near 14%. Also I might have problem in the code itself because it is complex so the numbers I get from the computer simulations may not be relevant. For now I assume they are. I will be glad to hear suggestions how to compute the probability. With computer simulations I also got that all possible ways of forming a 5 symbol cluster in 7x7 grid are 1086 I don't really know if this number matters.

Comment: This seems very much in the vein of _percolation theory_, particularly site percolation on a square lattice. There's a nice summary [here](https://pypercolate.readthedocs.io/en/stable/percolation-theory.html) along with references therein.

Comment: Could you post your code? I get $1603$ ways of forming a $5$-symbol cluster.

Comment: Strange but I am 80% sure that I calculated it correctly. I use simple backtracking and store all permutations without the duplicated ones you can find my code here https://prnt.sc/PfPyTxAkqKb1 I loop the method trough every element in the matrix as entry point.

Comment: Well, one in five times it's those $20\%$ :-). You're missing the ones that branch, e.g. [this one](https://tiermaker.com/images/templates/733781558493629.jpg). (By the way, that code is very inefficient, e.g. the clusters should be coded as bit patterns in long integers instead of double integer arrays, and you're executing the base case $4$ times for each cluster.)

Comment: This will boost the performance for sure. Yes you are correct I will think about how to count them as well. However, to calculate the probability mathematically is still difficult I am reading the suggested article but I still cant figure it out..

Comment: I don't think percolation theory will be of much use here. It's more about limits of large systems, not about the details of finite cases like this one. I'm trying to figure out whether there's some way to apply [Möbius inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#On_posets) efficiently, but I'm afraid the problem might be intractable; there are just too many configurations that contribute significantly.

Comment: I came up with another reverse engineering approach. To incrementally adjust the number of Bs in the pool starting from 100 to 250 and making 1 million simulations for each number to get the approximate probability. With the set of inputs and the set of outputs I can get an approximation of the function using Taylor series. Which is not the best solution, but if it is close enough it works.